# Templating Engine that works like Angular

Tags: angular, mustache

I've worked a lot with Angular, so I'm quite used to the

```
<my-component title="Some Title"></my-component>
```

workflow, where I can pass data directly into the component. Recently I've worked with mustache, and from what I found it's not possible to do something like this:

```
{{> my-partial title="Some Title"}}
```

What templating engines are there that support passing data to partials / components? I can't use Angular for this project, since I want to compile all pages pre-deployment into their actual html representation. So for each page I have, let's say `/about` and `/home`, I want to have `/dist/about.html` and `/dist/home.html` after the build process. It's going to be a static, non-single page website, but I'd still like to reuse some components. Mustache doesn't seem to be capable to do what I'm looking for (the above workflow), so what choices do I have?

Comment: I don't think there's a template engine like that. Template engines don't provide runtime behavior. Read [The mechanics of DOM updates in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/the-mechanics-of-dom-updates-in-angular-3b2970d5c03d) to understand how that works in Angular.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667011/is-it-possible-to-pass-variables-to-a-mustache-partial

Comment: @moondaisy thanks, i've seen this but i find it infinitely more complex than the way it works with angular, that's why i've discarded this solution.